# php symfony display categories and related products

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm bulilding website using Symfony 6 and PHP.I have 2 Entities:Product and category in relation ManyToOne(Each category has many products).

I would like to fetch all categories and display each category as separate div and all procucts of this category inside.So far i got this

```
public function index(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $categories = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();



        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    }

{% for category in categories %}
<div class="category">
   <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
   <ul>
     {% for product in category.products %}
    <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This loops display categories and products, but divs are duplicated like this:

```
 <div>
 <h1>category1</h1>
 <p>product1</p>
 </div>

<div>
<h1>category1</h1>
<p>product2</p>
</div>
```

I wolud like something like this:

```
 <div>
 <h1>category1</h1>
 <p>product1</p>
 <p>product2</p>
 </div>
```

What should I do? Make other query using QueryBuilder?

Comment: Please post the actual twig code you are using. The posted output doesn't match the template in any way or form...

Comment: {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello IndexController!{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        <div class="text-white">
            <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}



{% endblock %} that is all in twig template

Answer (score -2):

I found solution. It was my mistake as every time I added a new product, I also created new category. A simple method is needed to check if a category is created and if so, add a product to existing category, else create a new category.